# JavaScript output from constructor function comes back as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, constructor, return, private, public

When I pass a parameter into `setGear()` inside of `console.log()` the results come back `undefined`, why is this? The result should be the number I'm passing in.

```
var Bike = function() {
  var gear = 2;                     // private var set to an arbitrary number

  this.setGear = function(change) { // public method
    gear = change;
  };

  this.getGear = function() {       // public method
    return gear;
  };
};

var myBike = new Bike();

console.log(myBike.setGear(4)); // returns undefined, should return 4
console.log(myBike.setGear(3)); // returns undefined, should return 3
console.log(myBike.setGear(1)); // returns undefined, should return 1
```

Comment: `setGear` does not return anything, so `undefined` is the default return value.

Comment: setter should not return anything, the getter should...

Comment: @epascarello --- exactly! Maybe I should have made that clear before posting and my question wouldn't have been down voted. This code is from a Free Code Camp exercise that is suppose to illustrate a constructor function. I don't see the point in returning from ```getGear()``` but that's what they provided. I just wanted to see the results in node.js.

Comment: so add the return or call `myBike.getGear()`

Comment: @epascarello --- I'm just trying to make it work with the way the code was provided. I now see that their example is a bad example and I wish I would have seen that before fighting with it and then taking the time to post my question. I'm just going to leave it at that, but thanks for your input, it helped.

Comment: If I delete my question do I get my reputation points back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.setGear = function(change) { // public method
  gear = change;
};
```

should not return 4.

```
this.setGear = function(change) { // public method
  gear = change;
  return gear;
};
```

should do

Answer (score 0):

if you set the myBike.setGear, you should call the myBike.getGear function to return the gear;

`myBike.setGear(4);
console.log(myBike.getGear);`